# Why I can't loop xmltodict?

Tags: pandas, xmltodict

Ive'been trying to transform all my logs in a dict through xmltodict.parse function

The thing is, when I try to convert a single row to a variable it works fine

a = xmltodict.parse(df['CONFIG'][0])

Same to

parsed[1] = xmltodict.parse(df['CONFIG'][1])

But when I try to iterate the entire dataframe and store it on a dictionaire I get the following

```
for ind in df['CONFIG'].index:
     parsed[ind] = xmltodict.parse(df['CONFIG'][ind])

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExpatError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_31/1871123186.py in <module>
  1 for ind in df['CONFIG'].index:
----> 2      parsed[ind] = xmltodict.parse(df['CONFIG'][ind])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xmltodict.py in parse(xml_input, encoding, expat, process_namespaces, namespace_separator, disable_entities, **kwargs)
325         parser.ParseFile(xml_input)
326     else:
--> 327         parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
328     return handler.item
329 
ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
for ind in range(len(df['CONFIG'])):
     parsed[ind] = xmltodict.parse(df['CONFIG'][ind])
```